# Need to access method for 1 java class by another

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access a method from a java class by a another java class. I have created the object of the class and import the class into my java class but i am not able to access it my code.

```
   package com.example.musicplayer;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



import android.R.string;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Playlists;
import android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.FailedToCreateTests;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


        public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    public MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    private int currentPosition = 0;

    public MediaPlayer getmp(){
        return mp;
    }
    public void setmp(MediaPlayer mp){
        this.mp = mp;
    }

       @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
             super.onCreate(icicle);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         updateSongList();         
     }

            private void updateSongList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        if(home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0){
            for(File file: home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())){
                songs.add(file.getName());
            }
          }
                ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.song_item, songs);


        setListAdapter(songList);
      }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        currentPosition = position;
        playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), songs.get(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final String songName = songs.get(position).toString();
        //final TextView textchange = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.current_song_name);

        Intent in = new Intent(this, current_song.class);
        in.putExtra("song_name", songName);
        startActivity(in);

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "End of Song List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
        //textchange.setText(songName);
    }


    private void playSong(String songPath) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{

            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songPath);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    auto_nextSong();
                }               
            });

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    public void pause(){
        mp.pause();
    }

    public void stop(){

        mp.stop();
    }

    public void next(){ 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In Next()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(currentPosition < songs.size()){
            currentPosition = currentPosition + 1;
            playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(currentPosition));
        }
    }

    public void prv(){
        if(currentPosition > songs.size()){
            currentPosition = currentPosition - 1;      
            playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(currentPosition));
        }
    }

    private void auto_nextSong() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(++currentPosition >= songs.size()){
            currentPosition = 0;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "End of Song List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(currentPosition));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Next Song", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

     }
```

from the above class i am trying to access pause() and stop()

this is my class where i am trying to access

```
package com.example.musicplayer;



     import com.example.musicplayer.MainActivity;
             import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

        public class current_song extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


     public MainActivity ma;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle, MainActivity ma) {

         Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.songplay_page);

         if(extra != null){
             String song_name = extra.getString("song_name");
             TextView textchange = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_song_name);
             textchange.setText(song_name);
             textchange.setSelected(true);
         }       

         //MainActivity ma = ((MainActivity)getApplicationContext());
         //MediaPlayer mp = ma.getmp();

         this.ma = ma;
         Button btn_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause_btn);
         btn_pause.setOnClickListener(this);    

         Button btn_next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
         btn_next.setOnClickListener(this);

         Button btn_prv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prv_btn);
         btn_prv.setOnClickListener(this);

         Button btn_stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_btn);
         btn_stop.setOnClickListener(this);

     }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In Onclick ()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.pause_btn:
                ((MainActivity)ma).pause();
            break;

            case R.id.next_btn:
                //ma.next();
            break;

            case R.id.prv_btn:
                //ma.prv();
            break;

            case R.id.stop_btn:
                ((MainActivity)ma).stop();
            break;
        }

    }

       }
```

The concept is that i want to stop, pause the music which is playing. If my logic i wrong please guide me how to do it else please help me how to control my current music in Current music java class.

Comment: Use ma.pause() and ma.stop() There in no need to cast ma to MainActivity, as this is its type.

Comment: if I am not wrong, are you trying to access the methods of one activity from another? I don't think you can do that in android. Moreover even in Java you cannot access the non-static methods of a class A from another class B, without instantiating the class A in class B. If you can tell what you are trying to do in your code, we can suggest alternative methods for you.

Answer (score 2):

Please, move all your music playing code into Service. Activities don't work that way.

Consider the following:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

I think You are new to android but no problem: See you can not call the functions of activity from any other class like this (Object.method();)

SO For this type of handling You Should Create a `inner Handler class` which `extends Handler inside your MainActivity.` and override onHandle(message msg){} method of it.

And `When You start current_song activity pass this handler object in the intent.`

And when you want to perform any task from your MainActivity (like stop, pause), `pass messages through that handler` like `object.sendmessage(new msgObject("stop"));`

And `inside you onHandle() method call your stop or pause methods through diffrentiating command received from the message object.`

like `if(message's content == stop) MainActivity.this.stop();`

Comment: ya you are right i am totally new with android. Can you please show me an example how to it.

Comment: Sure I am adding another answer for that give me 10 min.

Comment: @shidutt even yet you have not not added answer.